# How to handle errors with Bash arithmetic operations?

Tags: bash, math, error-handling

Is there any way to handle errors with Bash arithmetic operations? For example, attempting a floating point operation, which is unsupported, results in an error:

```sh
$ echo $(( 3.5 + 1))
-bash: 3.5 + 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5 + 1")
```

My attempts to work around the error with either a logical OR or by just silencing the output produces no difference:

```sh
$ echo $(( 3.5 + 1)) ||true
-bash: 3.5 + 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5 + 1")
```

```sh
$ echo $(( 3.5 + 1)) 2>&-
-bash: 3.5 + 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5 + 1")
```

I do see how both fallback mechanisms actually apply to `echo` instead of the arithmetic operation itself, and that it is the latter that is throwing the error.

Is there a way to write one or another so that they do apply to the arithmetic operation?

Comment: The problem is that the shell itself is raising the error while *parsing* the command, before it tries to evaluate a syntactically correct arithmetic expression. The solution is to not write bad expressions in the first place. If the expression is hard-coded, that's trivial. If `3.5` is resulting from the use of  parameter expansion like `$(( v + 1 ))`, then you need to validate the value of `v` *before* attempting to use the arithmetic expression.

Comment: It looks like your root problem is that you need a bash operator that can handle floating point numbers. Have you tried `bc`?

Comment: Just wondering why no answer was accepted so far. [pjh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55170651/6770384) seems perfect to me. If it didn't solve your problem you may want to explain why so that others can give you the answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intention is just to discard the error message, then the natural way to try to do it is

```
echo $(( 3.5 + 1)) 2>/dev/null
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  I guess it's because the error message is coming from Bash itself.  However, this does work (at least on Bash 4.2):

```
( echo $(( 3.5 + 1)) ) 2>/dev/null
```

The `(...)` creates a subshell, which is very expensive on some platforms (particularly Cygwin and WSL).  This slightly messier code also works, and doesn't create a subshell:

```
{ echo $(( 3.5 + 1)) ; } 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

If your expressions never evaluate to 0 you could use

```
((var=expr)) 2>&- && echo "$var"
```

Some examples:

```
prompt$ ((var =3+1)) 2>&- && echo "$var"
4
prompt$ ((var=3+1.5)) 2>&- && echo "$var"
prompt$ ((var=6/2)) 2>&- && echo "$var"
3
prompt$ ((var=6/0)) 2>&- && echo "$var"
```

The only problem here is a false positive if the expression evaluates to 0

```
((var=0)) 2>&- && echo "$var" # does not print anything
```

There is a solution to this problem, but it is slightly longer

```
var=; ((var=0)) 2>&-; [ -n "$var" ] && echo "$var"
```